# what is the question mark in an angular template?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm checking out angular firebase documentation and I see this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <h1>{{ (item | async)?.name }}</h1>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  item: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.item = db.object('/item');
  }
}
```

what does the `?` sign after `(item | async)` do?

Isn't it ok anyway to do `undefined.someProperty` in the template?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: you could had easily googled "? operator angular" and found an answer to your question...

Comment: thank you wise guy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's call the 'Elvis Operator', or safe navigation operator. It notifies the template that a value that needs to be displayed may not be available yet, and allow the template to continue to be rendered and that value filled in at a later time.

It saves you getting 'undefined' errors when your template renders before data arrives, perhaps from a service or database.

Comment: Worth pointing out that if the attribute (ie "name") is known to be a non-null attribute, there is no real need for the ? operator when the async pipe is present. It might even be a problem, preventing a useful error if "item" did not load.

Comment: The "Elvis Operator" is  ?:   used in a shorthand if   expr ?  trueval : falseval